# Send purchase order details React Native Expo to user email

Tags: react-native, email, mobile, expo, cart

I have mobile shop cart, which has obviously a list of goods and a cart. I want to send information about orders to the registered user email, when they make an order. There is a good library EmailJS, that can allow you to send information to Google email. But I can't understand, how to send ItemListOfGood, and other specifying information (like delivery place or card/cash pay). Does anyone have a link or guide to the implementation? Maybe Firebase, but I didn't find anything similar.

```html
const MyCart = ({ navigation }) => {const [product, setProduct] = useState();
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      getDataFromDB();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  //get data from local DB by ID
  const getDataFromDB = async () => {
    let items = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cartItems');
    items = JSON.parse(items);
    let productData = [];
    if (items) {
      Items.forEach(data => {
        if (items.includes(data.id)) {
          productData.push(data);
          return;
        }
      });
      setProduct(productData);
      getTotal(productData);
    } else {
      setProduct(false);
      getTotal(false);
    }
  };

  //get total price of all items in the cart
  const getTotal = productData => {
    let total = 0;
    for (let index = 0; index < productData.length; index++) {
      let productPrice = productData[index].productPrice;
      total = total + productPrice;
    }
    setTotal(total);
  };

  //remove data from Cart

  const removeItemFromCart = async id => {
    let itemArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cartItems');
    itemArray = JSON.parse(itemArray);
    if (itemArray) {
      let array = itemArray;
      for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        if (array[index] == id) {
          array.splice(index, 1);
        }

        await AsyncStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(array));
        getDataFromDB();
      }
    }
  };

  //checkout

  const checkOut = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('cartItems');
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }

    ToastAndroid.show('Заказ скоро будет доставлен!', ToastAndroid.SHORT);

    navigation.navigate('Home');
  };

  const renderProducts = (data, index) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={data.key}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ProductInfo', { productID: data.id })}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: 100,
          marginVertical: 6,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            width: '30%',
            height: 100,
            padding: 14,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: COLOURS.backgroundLight,
            borderRadius: 10,
            marginRight: 22,
          }}>
          <Image
            source={data.productImage}
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%',
              resizeMode: 'contain',
            }}
          />
        </View>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            height: '100%',
            justifyContent: 'space-around',
          }}>
          <View style={{}}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 14,
                maxWidth: '100%',
                color: COLOURS.black,
                fontWeight: '600',
                letterSpacing: 1,
              }}>
              {data.productName}
            </Text>
            <View
              style={{
                marginTop: 4,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
                opacity: 0.6,
              }}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: '400',
                  maxWidth: '85%',
                  marginRight: 4,
                }}>
                Br{data.productPrice}
              </Text>
              <Text>
                (~Br;
                {data.productPrice + data.productPrice / 20})
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: 'space-between',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}>
              <View
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 100,
                  marginRight: 20,
                  padding: 4,
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderColor: COLOURS.backgroundMedium,
                  opacity: 0.5,
                }}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="minus"
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: COLOURS.backgroundDark,
                  }}
                />
              </View>
              <Text>1</Text>
              <View
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 100,
                  marginLeft: 20,
                  padding: 4,
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderColor: COLOURS.backgroundMedium,
                  opacity: 0.5,
                }}>
                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                  name="plus"
                  style={{
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: COLOURS.backgroundDark,
                  }}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeItemFromCart(data.id)}>
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="delete-outline"
                style={{
                  fontSize: 16,
                  color: COLOURS.backgroundDark,
                  backgroundColor: COLOURS.backgroundLight,
                  padding: 8,
                  borderRadius: 100,
                }}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score -1):

It can done only with firebase sdk. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: Please add the steps, how it can be done